# Searchcontroller Gives black screen after tableview dismiss drag and view.endEditing

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have implemented searchcontroller, I searched and the results appeared but while trying to dismiss keyboard while drag tableview the black screen appear on bottom of searchbar as provided in the screenshot. Please let me know why this issue occurring.

[image]

```
title = "SearchHistory"
        
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
search.searchResultsUpdater = self
self.navigationItem.searchController = search
search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by Setting

extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
in the UIViewController used to show the search results, fixed the issue for me.